# Determining terminal velocity using exponential functions

Tags: calculus, limits

I am having trouble with this problem.  Any help would be appreciated.

The velocity v(t) of a $184$ pound skydiver is approximated by
$v(t)=\frac{184}{1.1}(1−e^{−24.2t/184})$
where $t$ is in seconds after jumping from a plane.

What is the skydiver's terminal velocity? That is, in terms of the constants of the problem $\lim_{t\to\infty}v(t)= $?

Also, How long after jumping does it take the skydiver to reach $72$ percent of the terminal velocity?

I really do not know where to start with this problem.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: When $t$ is large, the exponential term is nearly $0$. So the limit of the velocity is $\frac{184}{1.1}$.

Comment: Is that the same thing as the terminal velocity?

Comment: Yes, that is the definition of terminal velocity.

Comment: How would I solve the second part of the problem?

Comment: Set the expression equal to $0.72\cdot \frac{184}{1.1}$. After some cancellation we get something like $1-e^{-at}=0.72$, where $a$ is the constant I am too lazy to type. Then we get $e^{-at}=0.28$. I prefer to write this as e^{at}=\frac{1}{0.28}$. Take the natural logarithm of both sides, and you are nearly finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice, the terminal velocity of the skydiver is given as 
$$\lim_{t\to \infty}v(t)$$$$=\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{184}{1.1}(1-e^{-24.2t/184})$$$$=\frac{184}{1.1}\lim_{t\to \infty}(1-e^{-24.2t/184})$$$$=\frac{184}{1.1}(1-0)=\color{blue}{\frac{1840}{11}}$$
Now, the velocity $v(t)$ becomes $72$% of the terminal velocity hence we have 
$$\frac{72}{100}\frac{1840}{11}=\frac{184}{1.1}(1-e^{-24.2t/184})$$
$$e^{-24.2t/184}=1-0.72=0.28=\frac{7}{25}$$
$$\frac{24.2t}{184}=\ln\left({\frac{25}{7}}\right)$$
$$t=\frac{184}{24.2}\ln\left({\frac{25}{7}}\right)=\color{blue}{9.68\ sec}$$

Comment: I understand how you did this but apparently it is still the incorrect answer.

Comment: Alright, could you please explain something wrong in the answer?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know the correct answer but I entered your solutions and my math website said they were incorrect.

Comment: You were indeed correct, but my very nitpicky math website wanted the full 9.67875 instead of rounding to 9.68.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

The equation of  velocity has the form:
$$
v(t)=a \left(1-e^{-bt}\right) \qquad with : \quad a,b >0
$$
As noted in the comment the final velocity is:

$$
v_F=\lim_{t \to \infty}a \left(1-e^{-bt}\right)=a
$$

and $v$ is $72\%$ of $v_F$, i.e. $v=\dfrac{72}{100}a$ if:

$$
\dfrac{72}{100}a=a \left(1-e^{-bt}\right)
$$

i.e.
$$
\dfrac{72}{100}=1-e^{-bt} \qquad \iff \qquad e^{-bt}=\dfrac{28}{100}
$$

can you solve this equation in $t$  ?

Comment: What does b represent?

Comment: In your equation $b=\frac{24.2}{184}$ is the coefficient , with positive sign, of $t$ in the exponent.